# How to update a List when binded to a ListView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a ListView which binds each list view item to a Class A which has a List

```
<Page
  DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel , Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding A.List}" >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          ....
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</Page>
```

And in my ViewModel, I have the class 'A' and it has a property List

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {

     private A _a;
     public A A {
        get {
        return _a;
        }
     }
 }

 public class A 
    {   
        private IList<IList> _lists;
        IList<int> List { 
            get {
               return _lists;
            }; 
            set {
               _lists = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("List"); 
            }
    }
```

In the set() method I has called 'RaisePropertyChanged()' whenever the List is set. 
But when I run it, the ListView content does not get update.
Should I raise RaisePropertyChanged("List") or RaisePropertyChanged("A.List") (like what I put in {Binding A.List] in my xaml? In my case, I set the List to another instance of a List.

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertychanged for this to make your listview update when the binded list updates?

Comment: MainViewModel inherits ViewModelBase from MVVM light framework

Comment: you are correct, but According to me your class A should be inherited from INotifyPropertyChanged to implement the update functionality on ListView.

Comment: That property A doesn't look quite right. Seems to be missing a Get statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this see if it works.

```
public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {   
        private IList<int> _lists;
        IList<int> List { 
            get {
               return _lists;
            }; 
            set {
               _lists = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("List");
            }
          }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using an ObservableCollection instead of IList?

Comment: @failedprogramming It seems that he wants to change the source of ListBox but not to add or alter the data into the collection.So I think Observable Collection can't help it.

Comment: I am using MVVM light, so I should inherit A with  ObservableObject instead. And the set() method should be 
                Set("List", ref _lists, value); , right?

Comment: @hap497  Didn't you set {Binding A.List}? Then it is not about A,but about List property.If you want you can replace IList with Observable<int> List{...} to have a test and see what will happen.